# PHP MySQL edit and update

Tags: php, mysql, set

I have the following fields in a database

- firstname
- surname
- username
- email
- password

There is an `id` field which is the `PRIMARY KEY Auto Incrementing`. I know that I have to use the `UPDATE users SET first name, surname, username, email, password WHERE id = 1`.

Obviously I will not be saving the password as-is (but a hashed version of it) but this is just for information purposes only).

What is the whole PHP/MySQL update syntax to edit these fields? Including entering the current data in into the form fields and only updating them in the database if they've changed.

How can I loop through each field in the table and dynamically make an input field for each?

Comment: What's your primary key?

Comment: the primary key is the 'id' field, it is an auto incrementing integer. the username is unique though, and also the end user doesn't have access to the details of the 'id' field.

Comment: You're looking for an entire CRUD solution. That's too broad a question.

Comment: So basically you need to learn the entire load from db -> build form -> edit form -> submit form -> process submission -> update database process? Would you like fries with that?

Comment: Fries would be good thanks @Marc B, large if you've got them. I know it's a big ask but it doesn't have to be scalable, as in my registration/login and member pages aren't OO, so they are very basic. If you start me off, I understand a lot more than I could do myself.

Comment: Check out http://speckyboy.com/2011/02/17/getting-started-with-crud-in-php/ (found via quick google for "php crud"). Didn't do more than glance through that, but it should explain the basics, otherwise google some more.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?php+crud+tutorial

Answer (score -2):

your update syntax is :

```
 UPDATE users SET firstname = 'name', surname ='sname', username='username', email='email', password = 'password' WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: I know what syntax I need as I had posted it in the question, its the load from database, build form, edit form, submit form and process submission parts that I am having difficulty with.